Home folders are file links, not folders?
I installed Ubuntu Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS yesterday and my home folder contains links to the standard directories (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc.).  Since the actual folders do not exist, the links point nowhere.  This is a new laptop computer, Acer Aspire 315, so could that be an issue?  When I installed Ubuntu on my other computers, there was no problem; that is, the home directory contained all the expected directories (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc.).

What do the links point to?  Do you have a separate "/home" partition? If so, is it mounted? Add requested info to your originall posting.
